# Maximal spectral norm of balanced $\pm 1$ matrix

Tags: matrices, discrete-optimization, bipartite-graphs, matrix-norms, spectral-norm

Suppose that we have a square matrix $A = [a_{ij}] \in {\Bbb R}^{n \times n}$ whose entries are $\pm 1$ and whose columns are balanced, i.e., $\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij}=0$. How large can the spectral norm of $A$ be at most?

Comment: How is this related to bipartite graphs?

Comment: Have you tried to brute force it for small values of $n$?

Comment: To any such matrix one can relate a bipartite oriented graph, where an arc is oriented to the right if we have +1, and to the left when we have -1. So, balanced column means that the number of incoming arcs equals the number of out-coming arcs for any vertex in the left partition. Spectral bound on that matrix is related to the question how balanced will be in-coming and out-coming arcs for vertices in the right side of graph.

Comment: I have not tried brute force.

Comment: Please include such information in the question

Comment: If it's balanced, $n$ is even, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146106/discussion-between-qwerty43-and-rodrigo-de-azevedo).

Answer (score 1):

It's just $n$. As $\text{Tr}(A^tA)=n^2$, we have the maximal eigenvalue of $\text{Tr}(A^tA)$ is at most $n^2$ whose square-root is at most $n$.

The upper bound $n$ can be achieved: consider the matrix $A$ with identical column vectors $v$, and let $w=(1, 1, \cdots, 1)^t$, then we have $\|w\|=\|v\|$ and $\|Aw\| = \|nv\|$, so $\frac{\|Aw\|}{\|w\|}=n, \|A\|\ge n$

Also, the maximal eigenvalue $n$ of $A^tA$ is achieved iff $A^tA$ has eigenvalue $0$ of multiplicity $(n-1)$, or equivalently $\text{Tr}(A^tA)=\text{Tr}(A)=1$. Hence $A$ achives maximum spectral norm $n$ iff all columns are linearly dependent (identical up to a sign based on the condition).

Note that when $n$ is odd, no such matrix exists.

Comment: Thanks! What if we have balance condition both for columns and rows? In fact, I am interested in $a_{ij}=(-1)^{ij \,\,{\rm mod\,\,}p}$ where $i,j \in {\mathbb Z}_p^\ast$ and $ij \,\,{\rm mod\,\,}p$ is a residue of $ij$ divided by $p$

Comment: I don't know the answer yet and after some quick numerical computations, I couldn't find a neat formula, but the general trend seems to be the norm squared is linear w.r.t $p$. At least $A$ is symmetric in this case, hence the norm is really just the maximal absolute value of its eigenvalues.